# Odoo Multiline Config File

Tags: configuration, odoo, odoo-14

One of the parameters in the config file has a long value and I want to put the separated value by a comma in the new line

From

```
addons_path = C:\My\Odoo\addons1, C:\My\Odoo\addons2, C:\My\Odoo\addons3
```

To

```
addons_path = C:\My\Odoo\addons1,
C:\My\Odoo\addons2,
C:\My\Odoo\addons3
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I haven't looked very deeply into it, but Odoo uses [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/configparser.html). So multilines maybe are possible by intending the following lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Supported INI File Structure](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/configparser.html#supported-ini-file-structure) section

> Values can also span multiple lines, as long as they are indented deeper than the first line of the value

The following `key/value` entry should work:

```
addons_path = C:\My\Odoo\addons1,
              C:\My\Odoo\addons2,
              C:\My\Odoo\addons3
```